# What Metrics are available for AWS SNS through AWS SDK Metrics?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

What Metrics are available for AWS SNS through [AWS SDK Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/metrics/AwsSdkMetrics.html)?

I've enabled it like this (scala code):

```
AwsSdkMetrics.addAll(Arrays.asList(AWSRequestMetrics.Field.values : _*))
AwsSdkMetrics.addAll(Arrays.asList(AWSServiceMetrics.values : _*))
```

I see AmazonDynamoDB and AmazonFirehose metrics, but nothing related to SNS.
What other MetricType's am I missing to publishing any interesting SNS metrics? Ideally, I could see metrics like latency, connection timeouts, request timeouts, number of retries, etc.

Comment: Metrics are listed on: [Monitoring Amazon SNS topics using CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html)

Comment: I think these are server-side metrics. I was hoping for client-side metrics. For example, would client connectiom timeouts show up there?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to AWS support and as of 09/14/2020, "SNS does not have its own client side metrics. SNS only support metrics at the server side "